# What version of Hibernate does CFML use?

Tags: hibernate, coldfusion, railo, cfml

The [Hibernate docs](http://hibernate.org/orm/documentation/) sometimes refers to differences between different versions.

What versions of Hibernate do ColdFusion 10 use? Is it the same in ColdFusion 9? Does Railo stable/bleeding edge use different versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All current engines use version **3.5**, but there are different point releases between CF and Railo. The latest CF beta comes with version **4.1**.

- ColdFusion 11 *BETA* uses 4.1.10-Final
- ColdFusion 10 uses 3.5.2-Final *<sub>(verified on u11)</sub>*
- ColdFusion 9 uses 3.5.2-Final *<sub>(verified on 9,0,1,274733)</sub>*
- Railo 4.x uses 3.5.5-Final *<sub>(verified 4.0.4.001, 4.1.0.011, 4.1.2.005, 4.2.0.000)</sub>*
- Railo 3.x uses 3.5.5-Final *<sub>(verified 3.3.4.003, 3.3.3.001, 3.3.2.005)</sub>*

Note: These are all older than the current latest version of Hibernate, which is **4.3.1**

The relevant docs for CF and Railo's version of Hibernate are [available here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/) and include a [single-page HTML reference guide for 3.5](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html_single/).

Previous versions of the Hibernate docs are available at: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/