# Error in generating Hibernate configuration with ColdFusion 11 / Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, hibernate, oracle11g, coldfusion, oracle12c

We've just moved to cf11 with oracle 12c.
Some of our Hibernate ORM queries are failing.
One of the errors is

> java.io.IOException:  Permission denied
>   "coldfusion.orm.hibernate.HibernateConfiguration$MappingGenerationException:
>   Error in generating Hibernate configuration.

I haven't been able to find out which version of Hibernate ColdFusion 11 uses - I wonder if it's not compatible with oracle 12c?

[What version of Hibernate does CFML use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21828017/what-version-of-hibernate-does-cfml-use)
only lists the versions of Hibernate used by previous versions of ColdFusion

The ColdFusion Administrator lists paths for the following jar files under *CF Server Java Class Path* on the *Settings Summary* tab, so I guess these are the ones used:

- hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
- hibernate-core-4.1.10.Final.jar
- hibernate-ehcache-4.1.10.Final.jar
- hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar

Comment: What OS is your server using? Does your ColdFusion user have access to the folders used in the Hibernate Mappings?

Comment: Thanks @Shawn, spot on! I actually missed your comment yesterday, but had realized independently that folder permissions were the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized in the end that the 'java.io.IOException: Permission denied' related to directory permissions on the server.
When I enabled write access on the directory the ColdFusion was running from, the error disappeared, and an ORM .xml file was created.

Comment: You should mark this as the answer. Glad you solved it.

Comment: It seems I can't do that until tomorrow - when I try I see the message 'you can accept your own answer tomorrow'

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with 'java.io.IOException: Permission denied'. It was related to ehcache underneath trying to open file in temporary folder. If this is the case there is no need to change permission on the whole ColdFusion directory. In my case setting 
`-Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/<folder_name>` on JVM and making sure that this folder has proper write permission resolved this problem.